# assert.deepPartiallyEqual function for asymmetric assertion of two objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, assert

I'm having a hard time finding good names here, but i'll describe what I want:

An assertion function such as nodes `assert.deepEqual(obj1, obj2)` but instead of recursively comparing `obj1` with `obj2` it should have a signature like so: `deepPartiallyEqual(spec, obj)` and just check that `spec` "fits" in `obj` or that `obj` "conforms" with `spec` if you wish. (Maybe a good comparison is [ramdas whereEq](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#whereEq) but it's shallow)

*(The context of the question is unit-testing)*

Example (pass):

```
spec = {user: {name: 'Elin', age: 30}};
obj = {user: {id: 1, name: 'Elin', sex: 'f', age: 30}};
deepPartiallyEqual(spec, obj);
// would pass
```

Example (**fail**):

```
spec = {user: {name: 'Cedric', age: 31}};
obj = {user: {id: 1, name: 'Elin', sex: 'f', age: 30}};
deepPartiallyEqual(spec, obj);

// should result in a failed test and an error output similar to:

AssertionError: ...
  + expected - actual

   {
      "user": {
  -    "name": "Elin"
  +    "name": "Cedric"
  -    "age": 30,
  +    "age": 31,
      }
   }
```

Does what I'm describing exist in any assertion library for javascript? On other platforms? **...and if so, what is it called?**

---

Motivation:

I'm asserting things on quite big objects but I'm only interested in testing that some of their (potentially nested) properties have the right values. So I only want to assert a subset of the objects keys. If I have to do a deepEquals my test file will be bloated with object literals with 90% of properties that I'm not really interested in testing anyway.

But at the same time, testing every property separately like so:

```
assert.equals 'Elin', obj.user.name
assert.equals 30, obj.user.age
```

...is a bit painful because it's quite many props to test.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function which on initial testing looks like it does what you need. It should be reasonably straight forward to add an error log to it.

```
function deepPartiallyEqual(spec, obj){
  if (typeof(spec) != 'object' || typeof(obj) != 'object'){
    return false;
  }
  for (var key in spec){
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      return false;
    }
    if(typeof(spec[key]) === 'object'){
      if (!deepPartiallyEqual(spec[key], obj[key])){
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if(spec[key] !== obj[key]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

**Edit**

Lodash's `isMatch` does what your looking for albeit without the error messaging. ([Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isMatch))

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };

_.isMatch(object, { 'b': 2 });
// => true

_.isMatch(object, { 'b': 1 });
// => false
```